# Access element's value in .val(),.text(), etc. without double selecting or caching

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an easy way to refer to the element's value that is calling the .val() or .text() without double selecting or caching?

For example:

```
//NO
$(this).val($(this).val() + 'something');

//NO
var $this;
$this.val($this.val() + 'something');
```

Instead, use something such as the $& token in .replace()

```
'some string'.replace('str', '$&123');
//results - 'some str123ing'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass a function to [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), like this:

```
$(this).val(function(i, currentVal) { return currentVal + 'something'; });
//another example:
$(this).val(function(i, cVal) { return cVal.replace('str', '$&123'); });
```

This works for any number of elements, in the function `i` is the index and `currentVal` is what [`$(this).val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) would get you.  Just return in that function what you want the new value to be.

Comment: Excellent!  I didn't even realize val() could take a function.  I need to read through the API more often. Thanks ;p

Comment: @John - welcome :) I didn't read the title closely enough...the same is true for `.text()` and almost every other setter function (`.height()`, `.width()`, etc)

Comment: caching a local variable would probably have less overhead than creating a function and making a function call. Especially because of the number of other variables created just to perform the function call...

Comment: @Nick I agree; that was never part of John's question. I'm more curious as to why you can't cache a local variable.

Comment: @zzzzBov - you're making an *assumption* there, `this` may refer to any number of elements.  You *can* cache a local variable, but that'll only work for single elements.

Comment: @Nick yes, i did make an assumption; you did too. I assumed he wanted performance or code simplicity savings, and you assumed he wanted expandability.

Comment: @zzzzBov - I made no such assumption...I simply provided a solution that works in *all* cases :)